# RavenDB: How do I query for documents by a property name that's changed case?

Tags: c#, json.net, ravendb

I "accidentally" had some documents stored in RavenDB with all the properties camel-cased  because of a setting made with the json serializer (            `json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();`
).

Now I'm storing new documents using Pascal-casing. Can I search for documents ignoring case of the property name?

Eg.

```
Old document format:
{
  name : "foo",
  someStuff : "buzz"
}

New document format:
{
  Name : "bar",
  SomeStuff : "baz"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed my problem, but I don't have an answer to the question. I wrote a console program that converted all the old documents into the new format by resaving all the old documents without the camel-case ContractResolver in effect. So all the old documents were saved with the properties Pascal-cased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the LuceneQuery to manually set the property name for the query.